# Thymeleaf. How to hide element based on boolean parametr?

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have a table of reviews

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="review : ${reviewsForMovie}">
        <td th:utext="${review.text}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But I dont want to show review if `review.isApproved == false`
How do i do that?

Comment: A simple [conditional](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless) will do what you need, for example: `<th:if="${review.isApproved} == false"`. Or maybe even `<th:if="not ${review.isApproved}"` (I have not tried this last one).

Comment: this is embarassing... I actuallly wrote this, but didn't checked if its working because I thought I also have to add smth like type="hidden". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each="review : ${reviewsForMovie}">
        <td th:hidden="${!review.isApproved}" th:utext="${review.text}"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I hope this works for you.  <td  **th:hidden="${person.deleted}"** th:text="${person.firstName}"></td>

Comment: You can edit your own answer and add the relevant (missing?) code - remove the comment when done.  Also, a bit of an explanations (along with the code) helps the community understand the answer better